# Excel VBA -- series are "unchecked" after explicitly setting series XValues / values properties

Tags: excel, vba

After running code like the following, to redefine the xvalues and values...

```
560            For i = 6 To 1 Step -1
570                Set oNewRange = objWbMaster.Worksheets(strLastWsName).Range("A4:A" & CStr(nLastRow - 1))
580                objChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = oNewRange
590                Set oNewRange = objWbMaster.Worksheets(strLastWsName).Range(Chr(Asc("I") + i) & "4:" & Chr(Asc("I") + i) & CStr(nLastRow - 1))
600                objChart.SeriesCollection(i).values = oNewRange
610            Next
```

...they are set properly, but if I select the "Select Data" option on the affected chart, they are all unchecked, like so:
[image: Image Description]

Does anyone know why this would be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well -- looks like I figured it out. There are some IsFiltered properties for the SeriesCollection and FullCategoryCollection objects that need to be set to False. The gist appears below:

```
objChart.SeriesCollection(i).IsFiltered = False
objChart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(j).IsFiltered = False
```